# Replace static cell address with one that can change when dragged

Tags: google-sheets, autofill, formulas

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet that pulls info from a master sheet based on an If function.

Here's my current formula:

`=IF(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "F2")="Site 1", (IMPORTRANGE("ID", "A2")))`

So basically, I want this sheet to check F2 in the master sheet for `"Site 1"` and if it finds it, return what's in A2 of the master sheet.

The trouble is that I want to be able to drag this formula down so that the cell below it will check F3 and then pull A3 and so on.

The issue seems to be that F2 is a string so Google doesn't automatically format this when I drag the formula to a new row.

Is there anything I can do to change the formula's F2 from a string? I've messed around with the `Address` function and got it to work but, again, the cells wouldn't update when I dragged the formula down.

Comment: `=IF(IMPORTRANGE("ID","F" & ROW(A2) & ")......` This relies on the relative reference to cell A2 in your current sheet. When you drag this down, A2 -> A3, and if you drag it across, A2->B2 (which is still row 2). `=ROW(A2)` returns 2, so `"F" & 2 -> "F2"`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reference A2 is a reference to the master sheet too. So, I want the current sheet to only pull data from the master sheet if that row has Site 1 in the F column of the master sheet.

Essentially, the master sheet will contain all the information from various sites. I need separate sheets for each site that will only pull information that's relevant to their site.

Comment: Based on my previous comment you should be able to deduce the appropriate modification to your second importrange formula. The A2 in my formula is unrelated to the rest of your formula -- it could just as easily be `ROW(Z2)` instead of the `ROW(A2)` I chose.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I managed to get it working now based on your first comment. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Feel free to write your solution as an answer and then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [tehhowch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326517/replace-static-cell-address-with-one-that-can-change-when-dragged/49328687#comment85654798_49326517), I managed to get this working.

Here's the working formula:

```
=IF(IMPORTRANGE("ID","F" & ROW(F2))="Site 1",(IMPORTRANGE("ID","A" & ROW(A2))),"No Result")
```